# How to replace multiple string in a single select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to replace strings in a table but couldnt get what I need. Below is the sample code for replacing strigns which I tried.

Problem: I need to replace the string 'CV7 + CV8' with exact matching values.

For eg: if I have values like CV7 1998,CV8 1998 which needs to replaced as `CV7 1998 + CV8 1998` without any duplicates. so my desired ouptut should be

```
CV7 1998 + CV8 1998
CV7 1999 + CV8 1999
.
.
```

How can I achieve this in a single selece statement ?

```
 Begin
Declare @variable as varchar(50)
set @variable = 'CV7 + CV8'

CREATE TABLE #CVtableforallyears
(
Outcomedestination Varchar(160),
TimeDimensionDatefromCV date
)
 Insert into #CVtableforallyears values 
('CV7 1998','1998-01-01'),
('CV7 1999','1999-01-01'),
('CV7 2000','2000-01-01'), 
('CV7 2001','2001-01-01'),   
('CV7 2002','2002-01-01'),
('CV8 1998','1998-01-01'),
('CV8 1999','1999-01-01'),
('CV8 2000','2000-01-01'), 
('CV8 2001','2001-01-01'), 
('CV8 2002','2002-01-01')

Select Replace(REPLACE(@variable,'CV7',LTRIM (RTRIM (Outcomedestination))),'CV8',Outcomedestination) from #CVtableforallyears
Drop table #CVtableforallyears
END
```

Comment: Post (add to your question by using [edit]) your **desired result**.

Comment: Hi... posted my required output... let me know if this is fine...

Comment: its just a small part of a large stored procedure  where I have this requirement to do...

Comment: Is the criteria to match based on the TimeDimension being the same, or the year in the string Outcomedest being the same?

Comment: Please post the exact desired result based on your sample data.

Comment: @EoinS... TimeDimension being the same...

Comment: will there ever be more than 2?  could you have CV7 1999 + CV8 1999 + CV9 1999?

Comment: yes it would be  :)

Comment: What if you do not have a match in your table?

Comment: that would return null value or a wrong formula....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ought to do you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  substring(
   (SELECT 
      DISTINCT ' + ' + t2.Outcomedestination
    FROM #CVtableforallyears t2 
    WHERE t2.TimeDimensionDatefromCV = t1.TimeDimensionDatefromCV
    FOR XML Path ('')  
    )
  ,4,1000) --just to omit the first ' + '
FROM #CVtableforallyears t1; 
END
```

It works for solo CVs and more than 2.

Edited to pare down the unnecessary .The example below demonstrates using `FOR XML PATH` and then how to use that in your full query.

Basically we concatenate the entire query into a string but use `''` to split where naturally `<row>` would occur; we concatenate each result with `' + '`.  Then you make your subquery only select matches to the parent query.  Using `DISTINCT` to avoid duplication.  Unfortunately there is no `LISTAGG` in TSQL so we use this method.

[Here is an example](http://rextester.com/VKZQ84858)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the REPLACE statement to do it.

```
WITH cv7 AS
(
    SELECT 
        Outcomedestination,
        TimeDimensionDatefromCV,
        RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Outcomedestination)), 4) AS year
    FROM #CVtableforallyears
    WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Outcomedestination)), 3) = N'CV8'
),
cv8 AS
(
    SELECT 
        Outcomedestination,
        TimeDimensionDatefromCV,
        RIGHT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Outcomedestination)), 4) AS year
    FROM #CVtableforallyears
    WHERE LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM(Outcomedestination)), 3) = N'CV8'
)
SELECT cv7.Outcomedestination + N' + ' + cv8.Outcomedestination
FROM cv7
INNER JOIN cv8
ON cv7.year = cv8.year
```

Here's the results :

```
CV8 1998 + CV8 1998
CV8 1999 + CV8 1999
CV8 2000 + CV8 2000
CV8 2001 + CV8 2001
CV8 2002 + CV8 2002
```